# How to automate the launching procedure of ROS nodes

Tags: ros, roslaunch, include, ros-fuerte, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am ***interested in automating*** the commands that I **have to type in separate new terminals to launch various nodes**.

step:1.**sudo su**

step:2.**cd /root/fuerte_workspace**

step:3.**source /root/fuerte_workspace/setup.sh**

Above three steps need to be **repeated every time when I launch new terminals(ctrl+alt+t). with following commands**

```
command:1 roscore

command:2 roslaunch move_base.launch

command:3 rosrun rviz rviz
```

**to launch command4**, I need to go **to /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/yujin_cmd_vel_mux**

```
command:4 roslaunch cmd_vel_mux standalone.launch
```

**Procedure One:** `Through shell script`
I have written a sample directly  [executable shell script](http://pastebin.com/xsPsVeF6). but it is not working properly and following error occurs in the new terminal when roscore tries to initialize.

[Script ERROR.jpg](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/13993889295103188.jpg)

**Procedure Two**: Through **include tag** in one launch file. But I don't know **how to incorporate rosrun commands inside a launch file.**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/161731/how-to-automate-the-launching-procedure-of-ros-nodes/) by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2014-05-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2014-05-06**:
step1: why do you need superuser privileges to run ros nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

step 2 and 3: you can add the line "source /root/fuerte_workspace/setup.sh" in your "**.bashrc**", located in your **/home** folder, so every time you launch a terminal, that command is executed:

```
cd ~
gedit .bashrc
```

than add the line **source /root/fuerte_workspace/setup.sh** in the end of that file, save and open a new terminal to test.

---

command 1: you do not need to run roscore when using a launch file, it runs it automatically.

command 3: you can add rviz as a node in your launch file, adding this line to it:

```
<node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" />
```

command 4: if you have sourced ros path properly, you do not need to go to that specific folder to run command 4.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2014-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2014-05-06**:
I am not very comfortable with ubuntu. My bash.bashrc is inside /etc. Can specifically tell where to add that particular line..
As you said rviz can be added as a node How to do that??

Thanks for quick reply..

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-05-06**:
In the `.bashrc` in your home (not in /etc). For adding a node to a launch check out almost any roslaunch example.

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2014-05-06**:
bash: /root/fuerte_workspace/setup.sh: Permission denied...........................................
When I open new terminal..

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2014-05-06**:
you should not have created your fuerte workspace on the /root dir. It is more usual to create it in your home folder (where you get with a cd ~). I recommend moving it or deleting and creating a new one.

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2014-05-06**:
Ok, that is the last option...But there must be some other way to solve this issue..

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-05-06**:
I would HIGHLY recommend that as the FIRST option. A ROS workspace should be in user space, not for root. You're just gonna get in more trouble with that. Unless you have a good reason that you know you'll need to have that as root, don't.